# Avoid "exception ignored" in python enhanced generator

Tags: python, exception, generator, coroutine

I have a coroutine (Enhanced generators) in python with some code to be executed after the end of data:

```
def mycoroutine():
  try:
    while True:
      data = (yield)
      print data
  finally:
    raise ValueError
    print "END"

co = mycoroutine()
co.next()

for i in (1,2,3):
  co.send(i)
```

The `ValueError` exception is not raised but the interpreter simply prints:

```
Exception ValueError: ValueError() in <generator object mycoroutine at 0x2b59dfa23d20> ignored
```

Is there a way to catch the exception in the caller?

Answer (score 14):

The exception *is* raised. The `finally` block is executed when the generator is closed. Closing a generator is done by raising a [`GeneratorExit` exception](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.GeneratorExit) in the generator context.

The exception in ignored because the generator isn't closed until it is being deleted (automatically in this case, when Python exits); the generator `__del__` handler closes the generator, which triggers the `finally:` block:

```
>>> def mycoroutine():
...   try:
...     while True:
...       data = (yield)
...       print data
...   finally:
...     raise ValueError
...     print "END"
... 
>>> co = mycoroutine()
>>> co.next()
>>> co.close()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in mycoroutine
ValueError
>>> co = mycoroutine()
>>> co.next()
>>> del co
Exception ValueError: ValueError() in <generator object mycoroutine at 0x1046a9fa0> ignored
```

Exceptions raised during cleanup are always ignored; see the [`object.__del__()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__):

> **Warning**: Due to the precarious circumstances under which `__del__()`
>   methods are invoked, exceptions that occur during their execution are
>   ignored, and a warning is printed to `sys.stderr` instead.

The solution is to not have exceptions being raised when a generator is cleaned up, or catch the exception by closing the generator explicitly:

```
>>> co = mycoroutine()
>>> co.next()
>>> try:
...     co.close()
... except ValueError:
...     pass
... 
>>> del co
>>> # No exception was raised
...
```

You could also catch the `GeneratorExit` exception and perform some cleanup at that point:

```
def mycoroutine():
  try:
    while True:
      data = (yield)
      print data
  except GeneratorExit:
    print "Generator exiting!"
```

but note that any exception other than `StopIteration` or `GeneratorExit` will always be propagated; see the [`generator.close()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator.close):

> If the generator function then raises `StopIteration` (by exiting normally, or due to already being closed) or `GeneratorExit` (by not catching the exception), close returns to its caller. If the generator yields a value, a `RuntimeError` is raised. If the generator raises any other exception, it is propagated to the caller.

Comment: The same thing happens if I replace `finally`" with `except GeneratorExit:`. I suppose it is the same...

Comment: @Zac: of course it does, you still *raise* a `ValueError`, don't you? Catching `GeneratorExit` and raising another exception does not prevent that exception from propagating.

Comment: Thanks so much for that link to the documentation. You saved me from hours of debuggin. Pretty bizarre that they don't capture a stack trace in the destructor.

Comment: @WalterNissen: why is that bizarre? When the interpreter is exiting, there is no stack any more to trace.

Comment: Because it's impossible to find where the ignored exception is being generated. It doesn't list the line or even the class, just the exception. We have 75K lines of Python and tracking down the one `__del__` that was doing an import and therefore causing an `ImportError` was not easy.

Comment: @WalterNissen right, but there is no traceback because there is no stack. There isn’t anything else to say there. Make sure your classes have good `__repr__` methods to identify them in the *Exception ... in [object_repr] ignored* error that’s written to stderr.

Comment: All I will say is that I am glad, e.g., syntax errors indicate the line in which they occur, rather than leaving me to guess.