# Can a generator take notice if a caller has called close() on it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

Given a simple generator:

```
def myGenerator(max):
    for i in range(max):
        yield i
```

It can be used like:

```
>>> gen = myGenerator(10)
>>> next(gen)
0
>>> next(gen)
1
```

When I execute `close()` on the generator, all subsequent calls to `next` result in a `StopIteration` exception.

```
>>> gen.close()
>>> next(gen)
StopIteration exception
```

Can the generator take notice on that? `yield` does not throw an exception. I'm looking for something like:

```
def myGenerator(max):
    for i in range(max):
        try:
            yield i
        except CloseIteration as ex:
            print("I got closed")
```

Comment: Off the top of my head - I think `gen.close()` is effectively `gen.throw(GeneratorExit)`... haven't had to think about it in a while though - or I might be thinking of a PEP - ugh...

Comment: Yes, it's `GeneratorExit` - [RTFM](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/).

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank goodness for that - I'm not going completely senile just yet then :p

Comment: Somewhat related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637048/avoid-exception-ignored-in-python-enhanced-generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jon mentioned in the comment, [calling `close()` raises a `GeneratorExit` exception](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator.close), which you can watch for:

```
In [1]: def mygenerator(max):
   ...:     try:
   ...:         for i in range(max):
   ...:             yield i
   ...:     except GeneratorExit:
   ...:         print('I got closed')
   ...:         raise
   ...:     

In [2]: gen = mygenerator(10)

In [3]: next(gen)
Out[3]: 0

In [4]: next(gen)
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: gen.close()
I got closed
```

Comment: Interesting... without the inner try except block, there is no exception.... Please add the link to the Python manual for other readers. Thanks.

Comment: @Paebbels that's because it's part of the generator's job to catch that exception (indeed it complains if you catch it and don't re-`raise`).