# single_process module works but getting different errors when using it

Tags: python, error-handling, single-instance

I have a program running and to be sure that it restarts in case it would crash, I have a cronjob, which tries to run it every few minutes, no matter if it already runs or not. For this I had to us the single_process module. The code is the following one:

```
from single_process import single_process
@single_process
def main():
    ... main code ...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I works and I get the following message when I try to start a second instance of it:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'> There is an instance of programm.py running. Quit
```

But sometimes I also get this error:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'> There is an instance of programm.py running. Quit
Exception ignored in: <function _ConnectionRecord.checkout.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7ff29a68e400>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 529, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 696, in _finalize_fairy
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1308, in error
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1520, in isEnabledFor
TypeError: unorderable types: int() >= NoneType()
```

Can anybody help? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I have got the exact same issue, I can't work out exactly why it's happening but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036540/what-type-of-message-exception-ignored-in-is has a good description as a starting point. In my case I have a bunch of threads running sqlalchemy stuff but I only started seeing this after moving from python2.7 to 3.5. No idea if the issue is with sqlalchemy, or my code. From reading the code of `isEnabledFor`, it seems that line of isEnabledFor is `if self.manager.disable >= level:`, which seems to imply that `level` is set to `None`. I can't see how that's happening...