# Generator function with h5py doesn't close properly

Tags: python, machine-learning, generator, h5py

I am trying to create a generator function to train my machine learning model and `yield` some images. Basically it goes like that (the minimum to reproduce the error on my side):

```
def generator(hdf5_path: str, primary_keys: list):
    while True:
        with h5py.File(hdf5_path, "r") as f:
            for pk in primary_keys:
                yield f[pk][0]

gen = generator('/home/coder/images.hdf5', pk=['AAA', 'BBB'])
for i in range(5):
    image = next(gen)
    print(image)
```

From this code I am supposed to get 5 images and then the `generator` should be shut down closing the `h5py` file. But every time the generator is stopped I get this `error message`:

```
Exception ignored in: <generator object generator at 0x7f41b112ab30>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/coder/workspaces/data_processing.py", line 420, in generator
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "/home/coder/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 461, in __exit__
  File "/home/coder/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 432, in close
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 267, in h5py.h5f.get_obj_ids
  File "h5py/h5i.pyx", line 37, in h5py.h5i.wrap_identifier
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
```

From what I understand this comes because the generator doesn't close properly but I am not too sure what to do about it ?

I also read that this could be potentially catch using try/error from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637048/avoid-exception-ignored-in-python-enhanced-generator) on the `GeneratorExit` but it didn't work (I can catch it with `Exception` but I want to understand more). The other message I read about this error were using a `selenium` package which I am not using at all (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480148/importerror-sys-meta-path-is-none-python-is-likely-shutting-down)).

Any idea ? Solution/explanation for this behavior ?

Thank you

Comment: You generate a new generator in each "for" iteration. Move "gen = ..." before the for-loop. This may lead to another error but is a step in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, my bad the code I am using is indeed looping only on the `next` and not creating a `generator` each loop iteration. I edited the message to rectify this mistake

Comment: The generator only receives two primary keys and can therefore only yield two images before failing with a different error. This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Agreed w/ Michael Butscher. You will only get 1 image from dataset `'AAA'` and 1 from `'BBB'`. Please share shape of the datasets so I can understand what `f[pk][0]` is reading. If you intend to read the entire dataset as an array, use `f[pk][()]` instead of `f[pk][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to diagnose your problem without more details about your data. That said, I can provide a simple example of how your generator might work for a file with similar dataset names and schema.

Code below is how I think you want your generator to work. Note that I fixed an error in the call to match the generator (modified `pk=` to `primary_keys=`, and put the keys in a list to get the size used by `range()`). Also, you don't need `while True:`.

```
def generator(hdf5_path: str, primary_keys: list):
    with h5py.File(hdf5_path, "r") as f:
        for pk in primary_keys:
            yield f[pk][()]

pk_list = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']
print('\ngenerator output:')    
gen = generator(hdf5_path, primary_keys=pk_list)
for i in range(len(pk_list)):
    image = next(gen)
    print(image.shape)
```

You don't really need to create a list of dataset names (aka keys) to read. HDF5 files are self-describing and you can get them with the `.keys()` method. Method below does the same thing without the `primary_keys` input parameter.

```
def generator2(hdf5_path: str):
    with h5py.File(hdf5_path, "r") as f:
        for pk in f.keys():
            yield f[pk][()]

print('\ngenerator 2 output:')    
# alternate method that does not require a list of keys as input 
gen2 = generator2(hdf5_path)
for image in gen2:
    print(image.shape)
```

Finally, it is simple enough to do this without a generator (unless you really need one for another part of your project). See code below for that method:

```
# alternate method that does not use a generator   
print('\nalternate method output:')    
with h5py.File(hdf5_path, "r") as h5f: 
    for ds in h5f.keys():
        image = h5f[ds][()]
        print(image.shape)
```

Finally, here is code to create the simple file I used to test code above:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
with h5py.File(hdf5_path,'w') as h5f:
    arr = np.random.random(100).reshape(10,10)
    h5f.create_dataset('AAA',data=arr)
    arr = np.random.random(100).reshape(10,10)
    h5f.create_dataset('BBB',data=arr)
    arr = np.random.random(100).reshape(10,10)
    h5f.create_dataset('CCC',data=arr)
```